# How to set correctly Matrix.orthoM for a textured sprite?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am testing to draw a textured sprite with opengl es 2.0. on android.
Demo works fine when I set ortho projection from - scr_w/2  to +scr_w/2 and - scr_h/ to +scr_h/2 with origin in middle of screen.

However if I translate to what I expect : 480 width (scr_w) and 720 (scr_h) height coordinate system + origin on top left corner of screen. 
then Texture rendering goes wrong.

```
Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0,  0, scr_w,0, scr_h,  -1, 1); //then texture rendering doesn't work ?
```

I have tried to set Matrix.setLookAtM differently to point from (240,360,5) to (240,360,0)

```
 //Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, scr_w/2, scr_h/2, 5, scr_w/2, scr_h/2, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // then texture rendering doesn't work ?
```

The Renderer class:

```
public class SimpleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

private final Context ctx;

static int scr_w = 480;
static int scr_h = 720;

private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

private Sprite spt1;


SimpleRenderer(final Context context)
{
    this.ctx = context;
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config)
{
    //Set the background color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    //Disable depth test
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Set alpha blend on
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    spt1 = new Sprite(ctx);

}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
{
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0,  -scr_w/2, scr_w/2,-scr_h/2, scr_h/2,  -1, 1);
   //  Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0,  0, scr_w,0, scr_h,  -1, 1); // DOESNT WORK ?

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, scr_w/2, scr_h/2, 5, scr_w/2, scr_h/2, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // DOESN'T WORK

    // Mix the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)
{
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spt1.Draw(mMVPMatrix);
}}
```

The Sprite Class maybe mess with shader or fragment in 2D coordinates?

```
    public class Sprite
{
    //Reference to Activity Context
    private final Context mActivityContext;

    //Added for Textures
    private final FloatBuffer mCubeTextureCoordinates;
    private int mTextureUniformHandle;
    private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;
    private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;
    private int mTextureDataHandle;

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; \n" +
                    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   \n" +
                    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;        \n" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;       \n" +
                    "void main() {                   \n" +
                    " gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix; \n" +
                    " v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate; \n" +
                    "} \n";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "gl_FragColor = (vColor * texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));" +
                    "}";

    private final int shaderProgram;
    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
    static float spriteCoords[] = {

            -50f,  50f,   // top left
            -50f, -50f,   // bottom left
            50f, -50f,   // bottom right
            50f,  50f   //top right
             };


    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; //Order to draw vertices
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; //Bytes per vertex

     float color[] = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1.0f };

    public Sprite(final Context activityContext)
    {
        mActivityContext = activityContext;

        //Initialize Vertex Byte Buffer
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(spriteCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(spriteCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        final float[] TextureCoordinate =
                {
                        1f, 0f,
                        1f, 1f,
                        0f, 1f,
                        0f, 0f
                };

        mCubeTextureCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TextureCoordinate.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mCubeTextureCoordinates.put(TextureCoordinate).position(0);

        //Initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(spriteCoords.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        //Texture Code
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "a_TexCoordinate");

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Load the texture
        mTextureDataHandle = loadTexture(mActivityContext, R.drawable.cathead);
    }

    public void Draw(float[] mvpMatrix)
    {
        //Add program to OpenGL ES Environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        //Get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");
        //Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        //Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        //Get Handle to Fragment Shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "vColor");
        //Set the Color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
        //Set Texture Handles and bind Texture
        mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "u_Texture");
        mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");

        //Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        //Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);
        //Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
        //Pass in the texture coordinate information
        mCubeTextureCoordinates.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubeTextureCoordinates);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);

        //Get Handle to Shape's Transformation Matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        //Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND_COLOR);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GLES20.glDepthMask(false);

        //Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
        //Disable Vertex Array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
    {
        final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

        if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
        {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

            // Read in the resource
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

            // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

        if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        return textureHandle[0];
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode)
    {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }

}
```